# Sql Server : Select Date between two dates and Display all results including duplicate

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Stuck in basic group by I guess.

```
select date,* from table
```

This is returning me some 7000 rows.

Suppose min(date) is '1989-5-12' and max(date) is '2005-5-12', Then

```
select * from table where date between '1989-5-12' and '2005-5-12'
```

Its returning me around 6000 rows.
Where are the remaining rows.? How can I get the complete result (7000 rows) with where clause of date between.

Comment: Why the MySQL tag, how's that product involved?

Comment: Data type for column date? Varchar??? Do cast as date if that's the case. (1989-5-12 is an invalid date literal...)

Comment: try **cast(date as date)**

Comment: Its a basic sql I guess, So tagged SQl Groups.
Data type is date only.
 @jarlh

Comment: the valid syntax for date is 'yyyy-mm-dd', if you need to convert it from another format, simply use `cast (myDateColumn as datetime) as formatedDate`.

Comment: Your both statements are invalid SQL. Any ANSI SQL compliant dbms should raise an error for them. Either your statements are not as written here, or the data type is not date, etc.

Comment: `select * from table where date NOT between '1989-5-12' and '2005-5-12'` AND see the dates

Comment: @jarlh, This is a correct sql query, only the column name and table name is different. Its returning the rows I have mentioned above.

Comment: @CM2K - I am using the same format. yyyy-mm-dd, as written above

Comment: Different names, and different literals...

Comment: @SubinCPoonamgode - Your Query is returning '0' rows :(, don't know whats going wrong....

Comment: that means ,there is no problem with this query `select * from table where date between '1989-5-12' and '2005-5-12'`

Check data..

Comment: Is the date field nullable?

Comment: `select * from table where date IS NULL OR date ' '` try this also

Comment: You could try SELECT [date], COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP By [date] to see which dates are in your table.

Comment: Guys, Thanks alot, null values were there, which was left behind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously you have `NULL`s in your data:

```
select * from table 
where date between '1989-5-12' and '2005-5-12' or date is null
```

Sample table:

```
('20150101'),
(null),
('20150102'),
('20150103'),
(null)

select * from table --will return 5 rows

select * from table 
where date between '20150101' and '20150103' --will return 3 rows

select * from table 
where date not between '20150101' and '20150103' --will return 0 rows
```

Comment: Yeah, I got it now, Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Please try below

```
select * from table where date>='1989-5-12' and date<= '2005-5-12'
```

Answer (score 0):

The remaining rows do not fit your where statement. To see the remaining rows just do:

```
select * from table where date NOT between '1989-5-12' and '2005-5-12'
```

Without any data we can not say why you do not get them from your select statement.